# Why FFmpeg print SAR instead of PAR?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, aspect-ratio

If my knowledge is correct, SAR (Storage Aspect Ratio) is the ratio of pixel dimensions.
For example, a 640 × 480 video has a SAR of 640/480 = 4:3.

Whereas PAR (Pixel Aspect Ratio) is ratio of pixel height and width, and most of modern videos have square PAR (1:1).

But when I tried to check it with `ffmpeg -i` I got square SAR instead of square PAR for all test videos.

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1758 kb/s, 24.99 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 540x360  [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], 386 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p,  450x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 5:4], 328 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc
```

Is it ffmpeg bug or my mistake?

Comment: Just made a ticket https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/ticket/2973

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it turned out, ffmpeg uses different notations

- SAR for Sample Aspect Ratio
- DAR for Display Aspect Ratio

Answer (score 18):

**SAR** (Sample Aspect Ratio) is the same as **PAR** (Pixel Aspect Ratio).

These two terms are used *interchangeably*. They mean the ratio between the width and the height of *individual pixels*.

In contrast, **DAR** (Display Aspect Ratio) is the ratio between the width and the height of the *full image.*
[image]

---

*Notes:*

**SAR** - All modern devices have it **1:1**; old devices — mainly from the analogic-numeric transition era — used *non-square pixels*.

**DAR** -  examples: For [SVGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_display_resolution#SVGA) it is **4:3**, for [QWXGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_display_resolution#QWXGA) it is **16:9**.